# Error setting up dpkg-dev and fakeroot

Tags: dpkg, mysql, database

When I tried to set up `dpkg` and `fakeroot`, I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
dpkg-dev is already the newest version (1.19.0.5ubuntu2).
fakeroot is already the newest version (1.22-2ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 4).
   Affected packages: mysql-apt-config:amd64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so you use the command `sudo apt install mysql-apt-config`?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}:${Architecture}: ${Status}\n' mysql-apt-config`? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix unmet dependencies for udev:amd64 error on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097066/how-to-fix-unmet-dependencies-for-udevamd64-error-on-ubuntu-18-04)