# unmet dependency problem while upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, dpkg, samba

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu version `20.04.2 LTS` to `20.10` so that I could finally upgrade it to `21.04` (Hirsute Hippo)

Once I run the upgrade command, I get this unmet dependency error:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsmbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6 is installed
 samba-libs : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I try:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  samba-libs
The following packages will be upgraded:
  samba-libs
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,282 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
E: Invalid archive member header
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/samba-libs_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 215241 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../samba-libs_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8) over (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8) ...
Setting up libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsmbclient:amd64:
 libsmbclient:amd64 depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8); however:
  Version of samba-libs:amd64 on system is 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6.

dpkg: error processing package libsmbclient:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for 
libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libsmbclient:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I want to eventually run `sudo do-release-upgrade` but before that I have to install all available updates for the release.
How further to proceed?

Comment: Looks like the same error --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097066/how-to-fix-unmet-dependencies-for-udevamd64-error-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

From your output:

```
E: Invalid archive member header
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/samba-libs_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb
```

This means that your `samba-libs` package is corrupt. Delete it from your local cache, and let apt download a fresh copy.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/samba-libs_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb
    # The file path/name is provided by the error message.

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
    # Apt will automatically detect that the package is missing and download it.
```